# Pylint: get output via script, similar to pylint executable's

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I use Python 3.3, Windows, installed pylint via pip tool.
I can run such command via "Scripts\pylint.exe" tool
(parameters important, i need special plaintext output)

```
pylint --msg-template="{line}:{column}:{msg_id}: {msg}" --module-rgx=.* --reports=n --persistent=n "D:\TestLint\sample_plugin.py"
```

This checks my file and gives such output

```
************* Module sample_plugin
1:0:C0111: Missing module docstring
1:0:F0401: Unable to import 'tst'
3:0:W0232: Class has no __init__ method
3:0:C0111: Missing class docstring
3:0:C1001: Old-style class defined.
4:4:C0111: Missing method docstring
```

Now I want to use pylint via Python code, not using any EXE tools. And want to have similar/same output for
my test files. So question. What Py script can I write to call pylint and get same output (in string or list)?

Answer (score 2):

There are several way to do so. The simplest being:

```
from pylint.lint import Run
Run([file_or_module, '--message-template', '...'])
```

If you want to run pylint in a subprocess (recommended for multiple runs), try:

```
from pylint.epylint import lint
lint(file_or_module, [--message-template', '...']
```